# C# code to run a batch file works in console application, but same code doesnt work in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

This following code is pretty simple and it works in a Console Application. But for some reason it does not work in a WCF Service. The directory which has the batch file has full permissions. Can someone help me? What am I missing?

```
    try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

            //specify the name and the arguements you want to pass
            psi.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatchFileLocation"];
            psi.Arguments = filePath; 

            //Create new process and set the starting information
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = psi;

            //Set this so that you can tell when the process has completed
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            p.Start();

            //wait until the process has completed
            while (!p.HasExited)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            //check to see what the exit code was
            if (p.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                logger.Write(p.ExitCode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Can you define 'does not work' ?

Comment: Yeah, what doesn't work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: The batch file is sending a file over SFTP to a different network location. If I run the batch file from command line (cmd.exe) it runs fine & the file gets transferred successfully.
When I run the batch file from a console app, the batch file gets executed & the file is transferred fine. But from WCF service it returns an exitcode 1. I cant see messages appearing on command line as batch commands are executed because a console window doesnt pop up when its executed from a WCF service.if its a console C# app the console window pops up & I can see what the error is in the messages appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this an IIS Hosted WCF Service.

Check the Identity associated with your application pool.

In IIS 7, and 6.0 to the best of my knowledge, this is the NetworkService, which may or may not have rights to the Batch file, SFTP, etc.  In 7.5 there is another account: [Default Application Pool ID Changed in IIS 7.5](http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/10/02/tip-98-did-you-know-the-default-application-pool-identity-in-iis-7-5-windows-7-changed-from-networkservice-to-apppoolidentity.aspx). It is also possible that your pool is using some other account, including a machine specific one, and not a domain account.