# Run a process from IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a `WCF` service hosted on an `IIS 7.5`. The service works well except from the part where it needs to launch a batch file. the code in the service that is used for this operation is:

```
            try
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\MyDomain\asp\Masof\App_Data\mish.bat";
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                return 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

the above code always returns 1, but the batch file never run (it supposed to do a text file manipulation on the server).
I tried to:
 - remove the `UseShellExecute`
 - add the following to the `web.config` file:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" />
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="administrator" password="1234" />
```

-Edit the anonymous authentication for the web application to a specific user (with administrator privileges)
however, none of the above worked.
In addition, is there any way to check if it's a permission problem? I've tried searching the event viewer but came up empty.
**EDIT:** don't know if it helps but when trying to run the process from the server (Start=>run...) i get a `The publisher could not be verified` warning before it runs.

Comment: Can this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189800/c-sharp-code-to-run-a-batch-file-works-in-console-application-but-same-code-doe ?

Comment: @Edward thanks for your reply but it didn't help.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `Process` implements `IDisposable`, which, in the simplest terms, means you should wrap its creation and usage in a `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the user profile linked to your application pool? Can you please share under which  pool you are running the app and under which account? Does this account have enough provileges to execute? The code seems correct

Comment: The application pool is ASP.NET V4.0. how can i know which user profile is linked to it?

Comment: aha.. I found for you a page that might help you out.. http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities. Under which user is the pool running? Also check the privileges of the user

Comment: I get a Page Not Found message when navigating to the page you suggested

Comment: Apologies...http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities